# How to add items into a calendar over more than one cell

Tags: qml, qt5

I want to try out the new calendar object of Qml in Qt5.3. Therefor I want to add some items (e.g. rectangles) into the cells at specific coordinates of the cell. To add a rectangle into one cell I use dayDelegate:

```
Calendar{
    id: calendar
    width: parent.width * 0.5
    height: parent.height * 0.5

    style: CalendarStyle {
        dayDelegate:


            Rectangle {             //the background of the cell
            id: cellRect
            color: "#505"

            Rectangle{              //a rectangle in the cell
                height: parent.height * 0.5
                width: parent.width
            }
```

Now I have a model in my C++-code which stores several items belonging to specific dates. That means you can have for one date more than one item. I want to show these items as rectangles like a list in the cell of the given date. So what is the best way to do that in QML? One item stores its date and a group id to which this item belongs to. I pass the items as a QQmlPropertyList to QML. I already realized a function which is telling me, whether for the current date an item is available:

```
function apAvailable(d) {

    for (var i in ApModel.items) {
         var item = ApModel.items[i];

        if (item.startDate.getTime() === d.getTime()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I can call this function in the dayDelegate passing the current processed day of the delegate.

```
Rectangle {
            id: cellRect
            color: "#505"

            Rectangle{
                visible: apAvailable(styleData.date)
                height: parent.height * 0.5
                width: parent.width
            }
}
```

Now my question: I want to show now all items for this date. So I have to draw one rectangle for each item available. How can I process this in the for-iteration of the function? Can I create a QML-Component and add for each item a rectangle into this component and then return it to the cellRect? Do you know a better way to realize that?

Another further problem will be that an item belongs to a group of items but each with another date(e.g. 3 days, one after another = 3 items in one group). I want to combine these items visually. In fact, there shall be one big rectangle starting at the first date and ending at the last date. In case of three days, this rectangle shall be displayed over these three cells. My first thoughts were that I draw for each item an individual rect but pay attention to the same y-coordinate within the cells. Is there a good way to group these single rectangles to have for instances only one big component?

I hope you can give me some advices how to do all this in a nice way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I process this in the for-iteration of the function? Can I
>   create a QML-Component and add for each item a rectangle into this
>   component and then return it to the cellRect? Do you know a better way
>   to realize that?

Did you try it? It really helps if you have an existing attempt at it that you can share with us, so that you can point out why you think it may not be satisfactory.

> Is there a good way to group these single rectangles to have for
>   instances only one big component?

You can use ListView, amongst other things. The [Calendar Example](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-calendar-example.html) already provides a similar backend to what you're describing, so let's use that as a base:

```
ListView {
    id: rectView
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.top: dayDelegateText.bottom
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.margins: -1
    clip: true
    interactive: false
    model: eventModel.eventsForDate(styleData.date)
    delegate: Rectangle {
        color: eventColours[index % eventColours.length]
        width: parent.width
        height: 10
    }
}
```

This doesn't take care of each colour belonging to the same group ID, however, because it relies on the assumption that events that overlap several days will be at a certain index in the model. However, until you share your attempt at the problem, this should give you some idea. The changes I made to the example, as a diff:

http://pastebin.com/U14iKUeQ

Or you can just replace the Calendar in the example with this one:

```
Calendar {
    id: calendar
    width: parent.width * 0.6 - row.spacing / 2
    height: parent.height
    selectedDate: new Date(2014, 0, 1)
    focus: true

    style: CalendarStyle {
        readonly property var eventColours: ["lightblue", "darkorange", "purple"]

        dayDelegate: Item {
            readonly property color sameMonthDateTextColor: "#444"
            readonly property color selectedDateColor: Qt.platform.os === "osx" ? "#3778d0" : __syspal.highlight
            readonly property color selectedDateTextColor: "white"
            readonly property color differentMonthDateTextColor: "#bbb"
            readonly property color invalidDatecolor: "#dddddd"

            Rectangle {
                id: selectionRect
                anchors.fill: parent
                border.color: "transparent"
                color: styleData.date !== undefined && styleData.selected ? selectedDateColor : "transparent"
                anchors.margins: styleData.selected ? -1 : 0
            }

            Label {
                id: dayDelegateText
                text: styleData.date.getDate()
                font.pixelSize: 14
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 2
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.topMargin: 2
                color: {
                    var color = invalidDatecolor;
                    if (styleData.valid) {
                        // Date is within the valid range.
                        color = styleData.visibleMonth ? sameMonthDateTextColor : differentMonthDateTextColor;
                        if (styleData.selected) {
                            color = selectedDateTextColor;
                        }
                    }
                    color;
                }
            }

            ListView {
                id: rectView
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: dayDelegateText.bottom
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.margins: -1
                clip: true
                interactive: false
                model: eventModel.eventsForDate(styleData.date)
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    color: eventColours[index % eventColours.length]
                    width: parent.width
                    height: 10

                    Label {
                        text: modelData.name
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        font.pixelSize: 8
                        fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it with my first assumption to add for each item a rectangle to the component, but somehow I can not access parent properties in the JS code:

`Rectangle {
    id: cellRect
 
   Component.onCompleted: {
      var component = Qt.createComponent("ApgViewItem.qml");
      var viewItem;
      var counter = 0;

      console.log("parent.width: " + parent.width); //parent.width is 0 ???
           }
     }

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try it. It looks really that this is a great solution :)
I tried it with my first assumption to add for each item a rectangle to the component, but somehow I can not access parent properties in the JS code:

`Rectangle {
    id: cellRect
 
   Component.onCompleted: {
      var component = Qt.createComponent("ApgViewItem.qml");
      var viewItem;
      var counter = 0;

      console.log("parent.width: " + parent.width); //parent.width is 0 ???
           }
     }`

Why is parent.width zero? When I use it outside the JS-code the width is okay.

Comment: It's better to use a paste site when posting code in the comments here. The width of the parent is zero because you didn't give it a width.